# AMChart handleClick to retrieve data from database based on item clicked

Tags: events, amcharts

I'm using AMChart stacked chart to report test execution status from DB. Php file with query is feed into the dataLoader and the stacked columns displays Pass, Fail and NoRun count data for each category. I'm trying to use handleClick function to make the column clickable and once clicked, a query is fired to retrieve data specific to that column's Pass, Fail or NoRun count data and displays the data on the same page. I'm not sure how to implement this. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Below is all I have so far, clicking the column triggers an alert with name of the category and a count, my goal is to be able to trigger a php file with parameters passed in and display data from DB,

```
// add click listener
chart.addListener("clickGraphItem", handleClick);

function handleClick(event)
{
    alert(event.item.category + ": " + event.item.values.value);
}
```

Comment: Please post your code so we can help you find an answer.

Comment: Is your "additional" HTML or some structured data, like JSON? Can you post an example of how the typical response would look like from that PHP file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been resolved by using JSON (converted from DB data in PHP) and AJAX to display. Within handleClick I call another JS function and pass in the graph variables that the query inside PHP needs.